# RabbitMQ SASL loggin

Tags: logging, erlang, rabbitmq, config, sasl

As with many RabbitMQ users, I'm seeing some large [MACHINE_NAME]-sasl.log files on my RabbitMQ nodes, containing nothing but =PROGRESS REPORT==== entries.

The stock answer I see flying around, is:

```
[{sasl,
  [
    {sasl_error_logger, false},
    {errlog_type, error}
  ]}
].
```

...but unfortunately, I never see mention of where this configuration needs to be placed.  I've tried modifying the rabbitmq.config file to include it and also updated the `start_sasl.script` file's `env` property but the log file is still getting populated with progress reports.

Has anyone managed to suppress these logs on a Windows machine?

Comment: What operating system are you using? If windows, there was a recent bug fix related to sasl log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

I've done some digging and found that [there's an issue with RabbitMQ v3.5.*](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/180)  involving excessive progress logging.

A workaround is to modify the `set ERLANG_SERVICE_ARGUMENTS` command in the  C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.5.3\sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat file (if you're running RabbitMQ as a Windows Serivce *which I am*) to the following:

```
set ERLANG_SERVICE_ARGUMENTS= ^
    -pa "!RABBITMQ_EBIN_ROOT!" ^
    -boot start_sasl ^
    !RABBITMQ_START_RABBIT! ^
    !RABBITMQ_CONFIG_ARG! ^
    +W w ^
    +A30 ^
    +P 1048576 ^
    -kernel inet_default_connect_options "[{nodelay,true}]" ^
    !RABBITMQ_LISTEN_ARG! ^
    !RABBITMQ_SERVER_ERL_ARGS! ^
    -sasl errlog_type error ^
    -sasl sasl_error_logger false ^
    -rabbit error_logger {file,\""!LOGS:\=/!"\"} ^
    -rabbit sasl_error_logger {file,\""!SASL_LOGS:\=/!"\"} ^
    -rabbit enabled_plugins_file \""!RABBITMQ_ENABLED_PLUGINS_FILE:\=/!"\" ^
    -rabbit plugins_dir \""!RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_DIR:\=/!"\" ^
    -rabbit plugins_expand_dir \""!RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_EXPAND_DIR:\=/!"\" ^
    -rabbit windows_service_config \""!RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE:\=/!"\" ^
    -os_mon start_cpu_sup false ^
    -os_mon start_disksup false ^
    -os_mon start_memsup false ^
    -mnesia dir \""!RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR:\=/!"\" ^
    !RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS! ^
    !RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS! ^
    !RABBITMQ_DIST_ARG! ^
    !STARVAR!
```

Then run the following commands in the order they appear in an administrative command prompt (CD'd to the same directory):

- rabbitmq-service remove
- rabbitmq-service install
- sc start rabbitmq

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

This should be placed into the rabbitmq.config file.  Before you make any changes take a look at this [explanation of RabbitMQ configuration from the RabbitMQ site](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html).